# async-await callback in express post with ajax

Tags: ajax, express, post, multer

If i use output variable that is commented & comment above output lines, I am getting alert present in success of ajax which is expected Where as if i am using output variable of await i am getting alert present in the error instead of the alert in the success.

```js
AJAX call:

    $.ajax({
                url:'/',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                cache: false,
                data: data,
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data));
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('Error: In sending the request!');
                }
            })
            

Express:

app.post('/', fileUpload.upload,async (req,res)=>{

  if(req.file !==  undefined){
         var output = await dbGet.getResult(`./storage/${req.file.filename}`);
         console.log(output);
         //output = [{'hi':'hello'}];
         res.send(JSON.stringify(output));
  }else{
    res.send('unable to process request');
  }
});
```